# How to find location of wifi packet floods

Tags: security, wifi, hacking

We've seen ongoing wireless packet floods (beacon, probe requests, and probe response floods) that are reported in the event log of our office firewall appliance. These are being sent continuously and has been on for weeks. We're in a multi-tenant tower so I have no idea if it's originating from our office or from somewhere adjacent to us.

The mac addresses used in the source and/or destination of these packets is constantly changing (cycling through ranges it looks like) so I assume this is the work on one of those tools like air-crack that's forging packets to execute a DoS. It's not actually fully denying usage of our network but it causes slow downs from time to time.

I understand that you can't block these packets because they have no distinguishable characteristic. But is there any way to determine the physical area that these packets are being sent from? I'm wondering about tools that can triangulate the location based on timing of packets.

Comment: You said it cycles through ranges, so first identify the traffic that looks legit and filter it out.  Also, invest in a directional antenna if you are going fox-hunting.  If nothing else in the packet is constant; such as TTL, then it will be a hunting exercise.  You could also move your users to another band and see if the attack follows, accepting this may prevent some folks from using wireless. i.e. 2 ghz vs 5 ghz

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aerodump-ng to monitor all wireless traffic for signal strength. If you know the temporary MAC of the source, start a capture by issuing "airodump-ng [interface]" where [interface] if the name of your wireless device. As you get closer to the source, the "PWR" will increase.

Comment: The problem is it seems to vary the mac address on each burst so constantly changing. But maybe your suggestion would still work if I can isolate the packets themselves by a filter...